# Facebook Graph API, share existing post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

How can I mimic the "Share" button below a post (see image) using the Graph API to re-share an existing Post to a group without re-posting the link? Is it possible to do the same using the Facebook PHP SDK?

[image: Facebook Post example]

Comment: You need to get the direct link to this post … in the UI, that hides behind the “1 hr” below the name of the posting entity. If you get the post by reading the feed of some entity, then you can assemble the link yourself by using the id you get for that post, appending it after `https://www.facebook.com/` (that is not the real URL that will show in the UI, but it will automatically redirect there.)

Comment: @misorude: What do you mean by the direct link to the post. Something like this? https://www.facebook.com/imapuzzlegame/posts/265284837373892 . If yes, what do I do with this link? How do I share it to a group?

Comment: Same way as you would share any other URL to a group …I assumed that you had that part figured out already? If not, go read up on it in the docs, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/group/feed#publish